# Can I work around name conflicts?

Tags: doxygen

I have a fortran project whith some name conflicts (from doxygen's point of view). Sometimes a local variable in a procedure may have the same name as a subroutine or function. For compilation/linking there are no problems, as the different definitions live separate lives, for instance:

- progA/main.f defines and uses the variable `delta`.
- libB/delta.f defines a function named `delta`.
- progB/main.f uses the function `delta` defined in libB.
- progB is linked with libB, progA is not linked with libB.

In this case, when generating call/caller graphs, or linked source code, the variable `delta` in progA/main.f will be identified as the function `delta`. Is there some combination of doxygen settings I can use to inform it that progA is not supposed to use definitions in libB, or something similar?

Another issue is that I may have functions/subroutines with the same name in different subdirectories. Again, as long as they are not linked together this does not represent a problem for compilation, but doxygen cannot identify which of them is meant in links, calls, etc. Is there some work around this (without renaming procedures, that is)?